# Is Season 2 of The Sinner also based on a novel?

Tags: the-sinner

The first season of [The Sinner (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sinner_(TV_series)) was based on a novel and was advertised as a limited run (aka, a mini-series). It was since renewed for a second season and is being described as an "anthology series" meaning a single season tells a full story but doesn't necessarily have any connection to characters or events from previous seasons.

**My question is: Is season 2 also based on a novel, and if so, which one?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not.  It's also not based on ANY of Hammesfahr's other novels. It's an original story.

However, it should be noted that *The Sinner* is a hybrid anthology series that's using Detective Ambrose as story axle character. Season two features him working on a new case, while also diving more into his own childhood. According to [this article](https://www.romper.com/p/is-the-sinner-season-2-based-on-a-true-story-season-1-was-inspired-by-a-novel-9964559):

> It looks like the second season of the USA show will be entirely
>   original. Showrunner and executive producer Derek Simonds **did not base
>   the new season on any particular true story, or on any of Hammesfahr's
>   other novels.** It's possible that details might be reminiscent of
>   actual cases since true crime is so prevalent that commonalities are
>   hard to avoid, but the goal wasn't to take inspiration from outside
>   sources.

And confirmed by an interview with Executive Producer Derek Simonds via [Variety](https://variety.com/2018/tv/features/the-sinner-season-2-derek-simonds-interview-1202880959/)

> The first season of USA psychological crime thriller “The Sinner” took
>   its story, structure and tone from Petra Hammesfahr’s novel. **But the
>   second season is its own, completely original mystery.**
>
> Without a pre-existing plot to follow, Derek Simonds created a new
>   story about why someone would commit a seemingly unprovoked murder.
>   This time the culprit is a 13-year-old boy Julian (played by Elisha
>   Henig), and it’s clear from the start that he is guilty. The show
>   follows the first season’s structure of unraveling the complicated
>   reasons behind the crime, a similarity Simonds wanted to echo
>   intentionally.